# exercise on the closed subspaces of an Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have a question regarding exercise 3.1.13 of "Analysis Now" by Pedersen volume 118 of the Springer GTM.

The exercise aim to show that any closed subspace $X$ of 
$L^2([0,1])\cap L^{\infty}([0,1])]$ is finite dimensional.

I'd like to get whatever proof of this fact, however in the book there is a hint which is the following:

- There is a constant $\alpha$ such that
  $|| f||_\infty\leq \alpha\cdot ||f||_2$ for all $f\in X$.
- If $\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}\subset X$ is a family orthonormal vectors,
  there is a null set $N$ such that

  $
  |f(t)|\leq\alpha\cdot ||f||_2
   $

  for all $t\in [0,1]\setminus N$ and $f$ in the linear span of 
  $\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}$.
- For all $t\in [0,1]\setminus N$

  $
  \Sigma_{k=1\dots n} |f_k(t)|^2\leq\alpha^2.
  $
- Conclude that there cannot be a family of orthonormal vectors in $X$ of size larger than than $\alpha^2$.

All items except item 3 are clear to me,
however I cannot really understand what is the reason why from item 2 one can get item 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** fix $t_0\in [0,1]\setminus N$ and consider the function $f(t):=\sum_{i=1}^nf_i(t_0)f_i(t)$.

Comment: thanks to both of you, I check this answer since I do not have Rudin's book available at the moment and this answer is self-contained.

Comment: You can upovote Norbert's answer.

Comment: I don't have as yet enough reputation points... I'm new to this place....

Comment: Oh yes, I realize you need two points more. Anyway, welcome to this site.

Answer (score 2):

See theorem 5.2 in Rudin's [Functional analysis](http://59clc.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/functional-analysis-_-rudin-2th.pdf).